# Ansible how to get output as variable without brackets and u

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have the result of a query from ansible and I tried to use the result as a variable

My playbook is like this

```
- name: Query
  oracle_sql:
    username: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    service_name: "{{ service_name }}"
    sql: "select smth  from table where smth like 'OK_%'"
  register: smth
```

The result is formatted as:

```
"msg": [
    [
        "SMTH"
    ]
]
no stdout, no stderr
```

After this I want to use my variable:

```
- name: echo
  shell: echo {{ smth.msg[0] }} > /tmp/test
```

and the outuput is like this:

```
[uSMTH]
```

How to remove brackets and 'u'? I know it's a list, but I can't get rid of this.

I tried to convert from yaml or json format without luck , this last add some return carriage with

```
| to_yaml 
| to_json
| to_nice_yaml
| to_nice_json
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 5):

The results that you got returned is a list of lists.  So a list of rows, with a list of the cells within that row.

Try something like this.

```
- name: echo
  shell: echo {{ smth.msg[0][0] }} > /tmp/test
```